# Android: How to constantly update/pass values from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, runnable

I am pretty much making a custom count down timer for one a activity and I am having difficulty constantly updating the value when I switch activities. I am able to udpate the value only once everytime I change activies.

Example:

Activity A -> B (default 0 on screen, user updates value to 10)

B -> A -> (10 on screen, user updates value to 10)

B -> A -> (35 on screen, user updates value to 9000) etc

However, once the user sets a time, it should constantly be updating it and counting it down.

I am able to update the value behind screen by a `Runnable`and printing out the values on the console, but I don't know why it wont constantly pass the value back to the previous activity, A, (so its up to date) and then have A pass it back to B when the user goes back to B.

I should note, that when I try ONLY updating the extras in `run()` and not in `updateTimerButton()` nothing on the screen changes, the default values are there, but behind scenes the values are updating (console).

Here is what I have:

```
public class CustomTimer extends Activity {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Intent intent;
    private Button timerButton;
    private EditText hourValue, minuteValue;

    private long startTime = 0L;
    private long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    private long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    private long updatedTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_timer);

        intent = getIntent();
        hourValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hour_value);
        minuteValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minute_value);
        timerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_timer_button);

        //avoid grabbing values from hour and minute if they were not passed for some reason
        if(intent.getStringExtra("hourValue") != null)
            hourValue.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("hourValue"));
        if(intent.getStringExtra("minuteValue") != null)
            minuteValue.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("minuteValue"));

        setUpHourValue();
        setUpMinuteValue();
        setUpTimerButton();
    }

    private void setUpHourValue(){

        hourValue.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                hourValue.setText(v.getText().toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpMinuteValue(){

        minuteValue.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                minuteValue.setText(v.getText().toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpTimerButton(){

        timerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                String hourTime = hourValue.getText().toString();
                String minuteTime = minuteValue.getText().toString();

                //only start the timer if it is not zero
                if (!hourTime.equals("00") || !minuteTime.equals("00")) {
                    System.out.println("starting runnable");
                    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    handler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("time is default\t" + hourTime + "  : " + minuteTime + "************");
                }

                //send the time values back to main
                //this does not constantly update the values, it only updates it once
                intent.putExtra("hourValue", hourTime);
                intent.putExtra("minuteValue", minuteTime);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();//go back to the previous page
            }
        });
    }

    private Intent getOuterClassIntent(){
        return intent;
    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        //update the time on the screen and constantly pass the values back to main
        public void run() {

            String hourTime = hourValue.getText().toString();
            String minuteTime = minuteValue.getText().toString();

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            int hour = mins / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;

            //update the time on screen
            hourValue.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(hourTime) - hour));
            minuteValue.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(minuteTime) - secs));

            System.out.println("updating time in runnable");
            System.out.println(hourValue.getText().toString()+ " : " + minuteValue.getText().toString());

            //pass the values back to main, but this does NOTHING if I comment out the previous putExtras (above)
            getOuterClassIntent().putExtra("hourValue", hourTime);
            getOuterClassIntent().putExtra("minuteValue", minuteTime);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, getOuterClassIntent());

            handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need data to be shared between multiple activities, it shouldn't be owned by either activity.  Create a service, have both activities bind to it when they're started, and query the service (via the Binder) when you need to know the value.  All updating of the value should happen in the Service.

Comment: Okay, so I pretty much just need to create my own Service and put most of my code from Runnable, but not the actual Runnable itself, in onStartCommand()  for the Service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use service for retain value of count down timer or you can use `event bus` for updating the values run time on your `activity`.

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(your activity);
```

and then post event when value change in your activity A or B

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(your value to post);
```

and override method `OnEvent(your data type)` to get your updated value

for refrence please visit
[this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-the-eventbus-library--cms-22694)